# Configuring new modes in Emacs: installing python-mode.el

Tags: python, emacs, configuration, dot-emacs, python-mode

I am trying to configure emacs with `python-mode.el`. I have done plenty of research, although I am still novice because I am not sure how to configure everything. I have used the following resources, which have been helpful:

- [Why I chose python-mode.el: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs)
- [General emacs modes info: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes)
- [Andrea Crotti explains his setup: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cZ7szFuz18](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cZ7szFuz18)
- [Andrea's configuration instructions via README.md](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/minimal-emacs-configuration/blob/master/README.md)
- [Andrea's init.el file](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/minimal-emacs-configuration/blob/master/init.el)
- [Jedi Repository](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi)
- [Python 2.7 installed via Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/)
- [Downloaded python-mode.el here](https://launchpad.net/python-mode)

I have been setting up to use Andrea's approach, and I believe that I have the resources, but I still have questions:

- I have a `.emacs` file, which I know to remove. Should I migrate the contents of my `.emacs` file under a new file, `~/.emacs.d/init.el`?
- Since I plan to use Andrea's `init.el` file, should I add it with the contents from my old `.emacs` file into a single `init.el` file?
- I extracted the python-mode .tar.gz file under `~\.emacs.d\python-mode.el-6.1.2`. Is this correct, or should I use a package manager like ELPA?
- From Andrea's `README.md`, I can install Jedi via `pip install jedi epc pylint`. Where should I clone the Jedi repository, and where should I run `pip install jedi epc pylint`?
- I have Enthought's Canopy python 2.7 installed under `C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User`, which has `python.exe` along with `libs`(with all the libraries I'll need), but I am not sure if this location will cause me problems in the future. Should I re-install python 2.7 under `C:\`?

I am using Emacs version 24.3
OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a .emacs file, which I know to remove. Should I migrate the contents of my .emacs file under a new file, ~/.emacs.d/init.el?
>   Since I plan to use Andrea's init.el file, should I add it with the contents from my old .emacs file into a single init.el file?

You do not *need* to. But I would recommend you to do so. Also you do not need to add your `config` to Andrea's `init.el`, you can have in a separate file say in `~/.emacs.d/my-config.el` and then load it from the `init.el` by appending `(load "~/.emacs.d/my-config.el")` to Andrea's `init.el`.

> I extracted the python-mode .tar.gz file under ~.emacs.d\python-mode.el-6.1.2. Is this correct, or should I use a package manager like ELPA?

I doubt you need this since Andrea's config already installs `python-mode`.

> From Andrea's README.md, I can install Jedi via pip install jedi epc pylint. Where should I clone the Jedi repository, and where should I run pip install jedi epc pylint?

You do not need to clone `Jedi` repository. You can run `pip install jedi epc pylint` from any location you wish.

> I have Enthought's Canopy python 2.7 installed under  C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User, which has python.exe along with libs(with all the libraries I'll need), but I am not sure if this location will cause me problems in the future. Should I re-install python 2.7 under C:\?

This should work fine as long `C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User` if in your path.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I have python-mode.el setup. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to run my .py script via `C-c C-c`: `wrong type argument integer-or-marker-p nil python`. Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Hi your issue sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190108/emacs-c-c-c-c-for-python-code). I guess you will have to save the buffer before doing `C-c C-c`

Answer (score 0):

Looks good and should work. BTW python-mode.el doesn't require a configuration at all, for a first try: just open and evaluate it. Loading at start is preferable, but mandatory.

WRT to package manager, AFAIK its not distributed by ELPA, try el-get for example:

https://github.com/dimitri/el-get

Should bazaar be available, current trunk offers bug-fixes since last release - and hopefully not that many new bugs ;)

```
bzr branch lp:python-mode
```

With release 6.1.2: save buffer before executing it--<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, not to run into a bug.